# Is there a way for Git Flow to Start & Publish a Feature

Tags: git, git-flow

Right now here is what I had to...

```
git flow feature start feature_name
git flow feature publish feature_name
```

Is there a way I can do both in one shot.

to finish it off, I do:

```
git flow feature finish -F feature_name
```

And that closes the remote as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost doesn't make sense to use Git Flow for this, because all you're doing is pushing a branch that doesn't have any commits that differ from your feature start point.  But from what I'm reading, there isn't a single command that you can use (from either vanilla Git or Git Flow) that would both branch *and* push at the same time.

This doesn't mean you couldn't chain the commands together, though.

From vanilla Git, you could use:

```
git checkout -b <feature_name> && git push -u origin <feature_name>
```

You could do something similar with Git Flow:

```
git flow feature start feature_name && git flow feature publish feature_name
```